# How to find an exact number of digits and characters in a string with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I want to match a String if it contains a maximum of 16 digits and a maximum of 11 characters, but with a maximum of 27 characters in total.

I tried `(\d{0,16}\w{0,11}){27}`, but it doesn't seem to work.

**Edit :**

**MATCH:**  `145214mkjnkj` or `1234567891011125abcdefghijk` (can be mixed)

**DONT MATCH:** `abababababab123` or `12345678910111213abc`

Comment: Can digits and numbers be mixed?

Comment: `123abc456def` should be matched too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get rid of the trailing quantifier, and use anchors to match the beginning and end of the string:

```
/^(\d{0,16}\w{0,11})$/
```

Where `^` matches start of string and `$` matches end of string. Now this will match a string with 0 - 16 digits, followed by 0 - 11 word characters. Keep in mind `\w` includes `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, if you want to match just alphabetic characters you can do this:

```
/^(\d{0,16}[a-z]{0,11})$/i
```

**Edit:** Since (apparently) digits and characters can be mixed, you can use one regex to test for invalid characters, then do some additional processing to determine if the minimum requirements for each character class are met with another regex, like so:

1. The first is a check to see if the string contains any invalid characters. If this **matches**, we know the string is **invalid**:

   ```
   if( preg_match( '/[^\d\w]/', $input)) {
       echo "Invalid input - Only digits and characters allowed.\n";
   }
   ```

   Note: The above assumes `\w` for characters, for only alphabetic characters, use `A-Za-z`.
2. If the above check passes, now we know the string contains only digits and characters, we test to see if it has enough characters by replacing all of the digits with an empty string, and checking if the remaining characters (which are only those in the `\w` family) are the correct length. Note the use of the by-reference `$count` parameter, named `$replacements` here, which will implicitly tell us how many digits there are in the string while we are checking for how many characters are in the string:

   ```
   $only_characters = preg_replace( '/\d/', '', $input, -1, $replacements);
   if( strlen( $only_characters) > 11) {
       echo "Invalid input - You can only have at most 11 characters\n";
   }
   if( $replacements > 16) {
       echo "Invalid input - You can only have at most 16 digits\n";
   }
   ```

Comment: @trouble - Your requirements in your original question were not clear. I've adapted my answer to comply with your changes.

Comment: @nickb I deleted my comment - all evidence has gone... my point remains

Comment: I try to test your regex `/^[^\d\w]$/`:  on `http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php` but it cant match **asdfa(dca) ** why?

Comment: @trouble - Because it had anchors when it shouldn't. It works [in my test case](http://regexr.com?31p9o).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want can be done easily or efficiently with REGEX. As I understand your question, you want the valid string to be maximum 27 chars long, and contain only digits and characters (as defined by regex `\w`) and only a maximum of 16 digits, and 11 characters.

To do this, the best thing is to run a few tests.

1. does it match only words and digits between 0 and 27 characters; regex: `/[\d\w]{0,27}/`
2. are there 16 digits or less; regex: `/\d/` and then count the number of matches
3. are there 11 characters or less; regex: `/\w/` and then count the number of matches

I don't see any benefit of wrapping it into one regex.

**N.B.** As pointed out by @nickb, the `\w` class contains the `\d` class, so it seems you would have to define your own character class to use instead of `\w` - something like `[a-zA-Z_]` which matches all latin (not foreign accented characters) alphabet characters and underscore.